# Flutter : FormatException SVG

Tags: flutter, svg

I have been trying to load an SVG asset on my flutter screen, however this error pops up :

> ======== Exception caught by SVG ==================
> The following FormatException was thrown resolving a single-frame picture stream:
> Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
> 215.98500072956085

This is how i try to load my image :

```
child: SvgPicture.asset(
    'assets/images/line.svg',
    semanticsLabel: 'shape'
),
```

I cannot figure out where the error might come from, did anyone face the same issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to open your svg file in text editor and check for

- the markup includes only English characters (maybe point or other character was input in not English keyboard layout)
- markup does not include comments <!---
- the markup is similar to the markup of working svg images

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed there was this line " <path d="M 4.6629367034256575e-15 1 L 630 1" fill="rgb(215.98500072956085,215.98500072956085,215.98500072956085)"/>" in my svg file where the colors inside "rgb" should be integers. I put 215,215,215 instead and it worked !